# Search Drupal modules by dependecies

Tags: 7

I need some feature upon Entity Reference module, To clearing I need rendered version of entity in form instead of just entity label.

So before writing new module or hacking Entity reference, I should search for exist modules.

It will be good if I can see all modules dependent to Entity reference. Where can I find sucj list of modules?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a module for this [Module browser](https://drupal.org/project/module_browser/) but it doesn't seem to be up to date at all unfortunately.

Comment: It may be a good idea for a high traffic Drupal related website

Comment: Sorry, what may be a good idea?